# image doesn't cover the full area of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to stretch the image to the size of the canvas. But the image takes its original size instead of taking the canvas size.Any help is appreciated.

```
              var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              canvas.setAttribute("width", "100px");
              canvas.setAttribute("height", "180px");
              //alert(canvas.height);
              myImg.width = canvas.width;
              myImg.height = canvas.height;
              var ctx44 = canvas.getContext("2d");
              ctx44.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
        // image gets displayed in its original size instead of taking the size of the canvas
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd ~ 4th parameters of [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) represent the *source* rectangle. That is, a rectangle from where your image will be cropped, before being applied to the destination, resized by the rectangle defined in the following rectangle.

Here is a simple demo:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = e => {
  const source = document.getElementById('source');
  const destination = document.getElementById('destination');
  const imgWIDTH = source.width = destination.width = 300;
  const imgHEIGHT = source.height = destination.height = 300;
  
  const src_x = source.getContext('2d');
  const dest_x = destination.getContext('2d');
  
  src_x.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWIDTH, imgHEIGHT); // simple copy to source canvas
  
  const source_rect = {
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    w: 150,
    h: 150
  };
  const dest_rect = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 300,
    h: 300
  };
  
  destination.getContext('2d')
    .drawImage(source,
      source_rect.x,
      source_rect.y,
      source_rect.w,
      source_rect.h,
      dest_rect.x,
      dest_rect.y,
      dest_rect.w,
      dest_rect.h
    );
  
  // show the source rectangle on the 'source' canvas
  src_x.strokeRect(
    source_rect.x,
    source_rect.y,
    source_rect.w,
    source_rect.h,
  );
};
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"
```

```html
<canvas id="source"></canvas>
<canvas id="destination"></canvas>
```

So in your case, if your original image is smaller than the 100x180px of your canvas, you are defining the source rectangle to be outside of the source image, this will then result in no apparent changes from the original image.

What you probably wanted was

```
ctx44.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.naturalWidth, myImg.naturalHeight,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

which is the same as the 5 param version

```
ctx44.drawImage(myImg,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

```js
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.onload = function(e) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 100;
  canvas.height = 180;
  var ctx44 = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx44.drawImage(myImg, 0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  document.body.appendChild(myImg);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
};
myImg.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbM0l.jpg?s=32&g=1"
```

Comment: It is still not working . myimg is originally 300 by 300 . Then I changed the height and width of the image to 180 and 100. Still no change

Comment: Changing the size of the Image won't change anything. drawImage uses the intrinsic size of your media. What is it you are trying to do? the last snippet in my answer will resize any image to a 100x180px one.

Comment: I have a canvas of size 300 * 300 and I drag and drop images to it. It takes the size of the canvas with no problem . Then I crop out different parts of the image and draw it on to a canvas and append it to a div. These cropped out images dont respond to the canvas dimensions.They dont even look the original cropped size.

Comment: ;-) Sorry but you realize there are like a ton of missing information here. How do you want me to be able to understand where you made anything wrong? Your question asked for some specific problem. This answer solved that issue. If you have other problems in your whole application, then set up a new [MCVE] showing where this other issue and open a new question.